# How to pass Map from Controller to jsp/javascript?

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, hashmap

Im trying send values stored in a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to javascript. Whenever the data is loaded and displayed using alert:

[image]

I know the reason is jsp/javascript cannot interpret it. Below are my codes.

In my controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/privateChat/sizes", params = {"sender", "receivers"})
    return privateChatService.getPrivateChatSizes(sender, 
            receivers.charAt(receivers.length() - 1) == ';' ? receivers.substring(0, receivers.length() - 1) : receivers);
}
```

In my jsp:

```
$("#hdnPcSizes").load(contextPath+"/dashboard/privateChat/sizes?sender="+sender+"&receivers="+receivers, 
                function (responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(responseText);
});
```

The `#hdnPcSizes` is a `hidden` field found in the same jsp page declared as `<input type="hidden" id="hdnPcSizes" />`.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek can you give some hint how to use json? Ive never tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From JSP call a the function which returns the value.

Use **net.sf.json** library

```
return JSONSerializer.toJSON(map);
```

Your dont have to worry about writing into the response.